# cmake does not link conan's installed library

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm setting up a c++ project, which uses cmake and has two build type:

- debug, having a `cmake-build-debug` folder
- release, having a `cmake-build-release` folder

I want to add `plog` through cmake, so I installed it successfully by defining a `conanfile.txt`:

```
[requires]
plog/1.1.5

[generators]
cmake
```

then, I `conan install .` on my root and I edited my `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    set(LLVM_ENABLE_WARNINGS ON)
endif()

# ADDED ROW
include(conanbuildinfo.cmake)

add_executable(primo main.cpp io.cpp io.h)

# ADDED ROW
target_link_libraries(plog ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

the problem is that cmake complaints about the last row:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "plog" which is not built by this
  project.
```

I'm new to cmake so maybe I've configured it badly. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: According to [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), you need to call `conan_basic_setup()` function after include `conanbuildinfo.cmake`.

Comment: The first argument to the `target_link_libraries` is **your** executable, which you want to link with the libraries (the rest arguments). Probably, you mean `target_link_libraries(primo plog ${CONAN_LIBS})`.

Comment: @adembudak is right. Or, you can use `cmake_find_package` generator, which is more transparent: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/generators/cmake_find_package.html

Comment: @Tsyvarev bingo, that was it!

Comment: actually now I get a `[ 50%] Linking CXX executable bin/first
ld: library not found for -lplog
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: I think that you need to remove `plog` from `target_link_libraries` and leave just `target_link_libraries(primo ${CONAN_LIBS})`. Plog should be available as part of conan libs